# Gathering biggest integer from table for each element in array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a column or decimal numbers, and a list of integers, write a sql query to return the biggest decimal smaller than each integer in the list.

| decimal |
| --- |
| 0.21312 |
| 2.34353 |
| 23.4534 |
| 34.3423 |
| 1231.00 |
| 1231.15 |
| 3213.32 |
| 23123.5 |

`integer_list = [2,50,2000]`

So the sql query should return a column as follows:

| decimal |
| --- |
| 0.21312 |
| 34.3423 |
| 1231.15 |

Here's my attempt:

```
WITH get_2    AS (SELECT MAX(decimal) FROM table WHERE decimal < 2  ),
     get_50   AS (SELECT MAX(decimal) FROM table WHERE decimal < 50 ),
     get_2000 AS (SELECT MAX(decimal) FROM table WHEREdecimal < 2000),
SELECT * FROM get_2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM get_50
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM get_2000
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Further suppose that I do not know the length of the list of integers, how should i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it using `CROSS JOIN` with `UNNEST` :

```
select lm, max(decimal) as max
from table
cross join UNNEST([2,50,2000]) as lm
where decimal < lm
group by lm
```

Result :

| lm | max |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.21312 |
| 50 | 34.3423 |
| 2000 | 1231.15 |

Answer (score 1):

An option that avoids aggregation is the following:

- union of your table and the unnested table, with a "*tabkind*" flag
- filter on the needed records, that are the ones whose lead tabkind is 'new'

```
SELECT decimal
FROM (SELECT decimal, 'original' AS tabkind FROM table
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT decimal, 'new' AS tabkind FROM UNNEST([2,50,2000]) AS decimal) cte
QUALIFY LEAD(tabkind) OVER(ORDER BY decimal) = 'new' AND tabkind = 'original';
```

**Output**:

| decimal |
| --- |
| 0.21312 |
| 34.3423 |
| 1231.15 |

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to adjust the syntax to work with BQ (I wrote this on Snowflake) but the following is probably more flexible/elegant:

```
-- Use a CTE to hold the list of integer values; alternatively write them to a table
with t_integers (integer_value) as (
    select * 
    from (values (2),(50),(2000))
)
-- For each integer value, get all the decimals less than it
-- then get the max decimal for each integer
select t1.integer_value, max(t2.decimal_value)
from t_integers t1
left outer join t_decimals t2 on t1.integer_value > t2.decimal_value
group by 1
order by 1
;
```